# Efficient way to compute average of outer products.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, statistics, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I have a ser of vectors $v_i \in \mathbb{R}^d$, with $i \in \{1, ..., n\}$. I have to compute a weighted average of the outer products of these vectors:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^{n} v_i v_i^T w_i
\end{equation}

where $w_i \in \mathbb{R}$. I have been doing this the naive way of just computing the outer product of each vector and then adding them together with the corresponding weights, but as the dimension $d$ or the number of vectors $n$ increase, this becomes very slow and memory consuming in my computer (I'm using Python). So, I was wondering if there's some efficient way of doing something like this, that I'm not aware of.

We can assume that vectors $v_i$ are all of unit norm, but they have no other useful properties that I can think of.

**Edit:**

I'm following up to comment on the answer by Carl Christian below. I tried it out and with only minor changes, I got an incredible speedup. The following code shows a reproducible example:

```
## Reproducible code
import torch
import time

nStim = 500  # Number of vectors
nDim = 900  # Dimensionality of vectors
v = torch.randn(nStim, nDim)
w = torch.randn(nStim)

# Method 1
start = time.time()
outerProds = torch.einsum('nd,nb->ndb', v, v)
outerProds = torch.einsum('ndb,n->db', outerProds, w)
sm1 = torch.mean(outerProds, dim=0)
end = time.time()
time1 = end - start

start = time.time()
vScaled = torch.einsum('nd,n->nd', v, torch.sqrt(meanW/nStim))
sm2 = torch.einsum('nd,nb->db', vScaled, vScaled)
end = time.time()
time2 = end - start

print(f'Method 1: Elapsed {time1}')
print(f'Method 2: Elapsed {time2}')
print(f'Method 2 is {time1/time2} times faster')
```

.

```
> Method 1: Elapsed 0.2266390323638916
> Method 2: Elapsed 0.003079652786254883
> Method 2 is 73.59239761554541 times faster
```

Comment: If you let $u_i=\sqrt{w}_i v_i$, then this reduces to the problem of finding a sum of outer products (though then these are not unit vectors). Whether this is any easier is not clear, but it does mean the weighting may not be especially relevant.

Comment: Yeah, weighting is not the bottleneck for sure. The modified problem would be computationally simpler if scalar by vector multiplication is faster than scalar by matrix, I could try that out. But I'd incline towards thinking that Pytorch being as optimized as it is, it shouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do significantly better than computing a sum of outer products.

Your are computing the matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$ given by $$A = \sum_{j=1}^n v_j v_j^T w_j. $$ I prefer to write this as $$A = \sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j v_j v_j^T$$ because it very common to use $u$, $v$ and $w$ for vectors and lower-case Greek letters for scalars. If we define a diagonal matrix $D$ by $$D = \text{diag}\{\lambda_1,\lambda_2, \dotsc, \lambda_n \} $$ and a rectangular matrix $V \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times n}$ by $$V = \begin{bmatrix} v_1 & v_2 & \dotsc & v_n\end{bmatrix} $$ then $$A = VDV^T$$

I will assume that you store the matrix $V$ using column major format. You should then compute $A$ as $$Y = VD, \quad A = Y V^T.$$ The calculation of $Y$ is almost certainly inefficient, while the calculation of $A = YV^T$ can almost certainly be done efficiently using dense matrix matrix multiplication, i.e., BLAS3 operations. The first calculations is likely memory bound while the second calculation is likely computed bound. The issue is the so-called arithmetic intensity of the individual steps.

The arithmetic intensity of a step of an algorithm is the number of arithmetic operations performed divided by the number of memory operations. A modern computer can do many floating point operations in the time that it takes to move a single word from main memory into the level-1 cache. This is famous memory wall. As a result, modern computers can achieve a significant percentage of the peak flop rate when the arithmetic intensity is high and they are likely to do poorly when the arithmetic intensity is low. When deciding which algorithm to use, it not enough to consider the number of floating point operations, we must consider the memory traffic as well.

What is the arithmetic intensity of the proposed solutions? I suspect that you have $n \leq d$ as I rarely need more vectors than I have dimensions. Let us take $n = d$ and compute the arithmetic intensity of the different steps.

If $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then $vv^T \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and the arithmetic intensity is $O(1)$ depending on how we do it. If we do not exploit the symmetric, then we need to compute $n^2$ products and we need to write $n^2$ results to main memory. In this case, the arithmetic intensity is less $1$ because we also need to read the vector $v$ at least once. If we try to exploit the symmetry, then we need to avoid the penalty associated with cache misses.

Scaling a vector requires us to read/write the vector and perform a single arithmetic operations per element. The arithmetic intensity is $1/2$.

Computing $A = YV^T$ where $Y, V \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ requires us to read $2n^2$ words, write $n^2$ words and do $O(n^3)$ arithmetic operations. The arithmetic intensity is $O(n)$. It follows that $YV^T$ can be computed efficiently using dense matrix matrix multiplication. Do not do this in python yourself, but call the BLAS3 library routine dgemm. The python library scipy has wrappers for many BLAS functions. A good vendor implementation of dgemm will have 6 nested loops while the mathematical definition of a matrix product suggests that we should have 3. It will use AVX vector operations (SIMD) instead of the scalar operations that we are likely to get if we write a simple implementation in python.

Computing $A$ by summing $n$ terms of the form $\lambda_j v_j v_j^T$ is almost certainly the worst possible solution because you are executing a sequence of memory bound operations. In particular, you have to write at least $n^3$ words somewhere. You might have enough level-3 cache to hold $n^2$ words, but if you could do everything in your level-1 cache, then you would not have had an issue in the first place.

If you compute $Y = VD$ by scaling the columns of $V$, then you need to read $n^2+n$ words, write $n^2$ words and do $n^2$ flops. The arithmetic intensity of this is slightly less than $1/2$. The runtime is dominated by the need to move $2n^2+n$ words. You then do $A = YV^T$ with arithmetic intensity $O(n)$. Then time to complete the second step is dominated by the arithmetic operations that you have to complete.

Both approaches are doing the same number of floating point operations, but one is doing significantly more memory operations.

I include a simple MATLAB script that illustrates the difference. I have written the code to use vector operations whenever possible. The matrix matrix multiplication will resolve to a call to your vendors dgemm function.

```
% Set the dimension of the problem
d=1000; n=500;

% Seed the generator
rng(2023);

% Generate random matrices 
V=rand(d,n); lambda=rand(n,1); Y=zeros(d,n);

% Make copies for the second experiment
V1=V; lambda1=lambda;

% Start timing the operations Y=V*D
t0=cputime;

% Compute Y=V*D by scaling the columns of V
for j=1:n
  Y(:,j)=V(:,j)*lambda(j);
end

% Start time the matrix matrix multiplication
t1=cputime;

% Compute A=Y*V' using BLAS operations
A=Y*V';

% Make the end of first experiment
t2=cputime;

% Initialize the output
A1=zeros(d,d);

% Start timing the second approach.
s0=cputime;

% Compute the matrix A using a sum of outer products
for j=1:n
    A1=A1+lambda(j)*V1(:,j)*V1(:,j)';
end

% Mark the end of the second approach
s1=cputime;

% Compute the relative difference between the two results.
% This number would be zero in exact arithmetic.
err=norm(A1-A)/norm(A);

% Display results 
fprintf('Approach based on DGEMM       Approach based on outer products\n');
fprintf('Column scaling %10.2e       Simple loop        %10.2e \n',t1-t0,s1-s0);
fprintf('DGEMM          %10.2e                                 \n',t2-t1);
fprintf('Total time     %10.2e                          %10.2e \n',t2-t0,s1-s0);
fprintf('Speedup of DGEMM over outer product : %d\n',floor((s1-s0)/(t2-t0)));
fprintf('Normwise relative error = %10.2e\n',err);
```

On my desktop a typical result is this.

```
Approach based on DGEMM       Approach based on outer products
Column scaling   0.00e+00       Simple loop          1.91e+00 
DGEMM            3.00e-02                                 
Total time       3.00e-02                            1.91e+00 
Speedup of DGEMM over outer product : 63
Normwise relative error =   3.74e-17
```

Comment: Wow, this is amazing,. I will try out this solution, and if it works as it should, I will mark as the correct answer. Thank you very much for the extremely thorough step by step explanation. I hope that you have a great day.

Comment: Marked as the correct answer. The speedup I got is bananas, I'm very grateful for your generous help!!!

Comment: @dherrera Thank you for your kind words that made my day.

Answer (score -1):

Timewise, I doubt there are any optimizations here other than the one suggested by Semiclassical in a comment.

Spacewise (since you mention memory consumption), an obvious optimization is to add up the outer products one at a time, rather than computing and storing all of them and only then adding them; this reduces the space requirement by a factor $\frac{n+1}2$ (with $2$ matrices stored simultaneously instead of $n+1$).